# How do I configure webpack to inject the global object in a manner compatible with strict mode?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, webpack

My goal is to concatenate the Socket.IO-Client with some custom scripts. The problem is that in my custom scripts the strict mode is enabled globally. The Socket.IO-Client fails in strict mode.

The reason for this is the injection of the global object by webpack. To demonstrate the issue I created the following example script app.js:

```
global.dummy = true;
```

Calling `webpack ./app.js app.bundle.js` creates an output containing the following lines:

```
/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function(global) {global.dummy = true;
/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */}.call(exports, (function() { return this; }())))
```

As you can see the global object is injected using `(function() { return this; }())`. This does not work in strict mode. (`global` is undefined and `global.dummy` throws an exception.)

Is there any option to change this injection behavior in webpack?

When I replace the injection code `(function() { return this; }())` with `(function() { return window; }())` the script works. I would like to configure this in webpack.

**What I tried:**

I created a webpack config file and set `target` to all possible values. No success.

The webpack config from the Socket.IO-client contains the following:

```
externals: {
  global: glob()
},
...
function glob () {
  return 'typeof self !== "undefined" ? self : ' +
    'typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : ' +
    'typeof global !== "undefined" ? global : {}';
}
```

Adding this to my webpack config file does not change the output at all.

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm trying to import a library that was built with Webpack, but because of use strict the global that's passed in is `undefined`.

Comment: @MattZeunert Have you resolved your problem?